# How to merge and sum nested hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I have a few hash objects that look like the following.

```
stats1 = {
  "Test1" => {
    "Variant A" => 10,
    "Variant B" => 20
  },
  "Test2" => {
    "Variant C" => 30,
    "Variant D" => 40
  }
}

stats2 = {
   "Test1" => {
     "Variant A" => 1,
     "Variant B" => 2
   },
   "Test2" => {
     "Variant C" => 3,
     "Variant D" => 4
   }
}
```

I want a function that takes as input an arbitrary number of similarly structured hash objects and returns a result summing the values, as such.

```
stats3 = {
  "Test1" => {
     "Variant A" => 11,
     "Variant B" => 22
  },
  "Test2" => {
     "Variant C" => 33,
     "Variant D" => 44
  }
}
```

They are guaranteed to have the same keys, but will have different values for the integers. I would like to merge these into one object with all the same keys, and the values are the sums of the all the numbers. I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is.

**EDIT:** If possible I would like a generic answer, meaning the solution will work for any number of levels of nesting.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the expected output for this input?

Comment: What is the expected output for the example given in question?  There are no `same keys` in the example.

Comment: Updated it, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: You should show an example of n-levels nested structure.

Comment: I think the description suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I think you want something like this:

```
stats1 = {
  "Test1" => { "Variant A" => 34, "Variant B" => 64 },
  "Test2" => { "Variant C" => 23, "Variant D" => 314 }
}

stats2 = {
  "Test1" => { "Variant A" => 100, "Variant B" => 200 },
  "Test2" => { "Variant C" => 300, "Variant D" => 400 }
}

stats3 = {
  "Test1" => { "Variant A" => 1000, "Variant B" => 2000 },
  "Test2" => { "Variant C" => 3000, "Variant D" => 4000 }
}

def sum_stats(*hashes)
  hashes.reduce({}) do |sums, stats|
    sums.merge(stats) do |_, prev_hsh, new_hsh|
      prev_hsh.merge(new_hsh) {|_, prev_val, new_val| prev_val + new_val }
    end
  end
end

sum_stats(stats1, stats2, stats3)    
# => {
#   "Test1" => { "Variant A" => 1134, "Variant B" => 2264 },
#   "Test2" => { "Variant C" => 3323, "Variant D" => 4714 }
# }
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I updated my question with a further requirement. Sorry if the question wasn't clear but you answered it correctly.